# Controller makes robot unstable in Gazebo

Tags: ros, microcontroller, gazebo, simulation, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte, Gazebo 1.6.16

Hi all,
I've setup a robot model in a world. I start the simulation paused and everything is ok, but when I press 'play' the controller won't hold the robots position.

From it's resting position, it actually jiggles a bit then flops the links to one side. I've tried adjusting the parameters...
I wonder if my robot's mass is too light. The measurements are accurate, but being in meter units the inertia matrix is very small for each link.

e.g. for one link:

```
<inertial>
    <mass value="0.5692" />
    <origin xyz="-0.000000157 0.014876512 0.044359344"/>
    <inertia ixx="0.001427609768" ixy="-0.000000003731" ixz="0.000000282945" 
                                  iyy= "0.000797193532" iyz="0.000106505679" 
                                                        izz= "0.001191235228" />
</inertial>
```

I'm using the
robot_mechanism_controllers/JointPositionController
controller for each joint, with:

```
  pid:
    p: 2.0
    i: 0.0
    d: 0.5
    i_clamp: 0.0
```

Gazebo settings in the URDF are

```
<dynamics damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>

<selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
<static>false</static>
<turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
```

Do I need to set these other parameters?:

```
<initial_joint_position>    ?
<stopKd value="1.0" />   ?
<stopKp value="1000000.0" />   ?
```

World settings are:

```
<physics type="ode">
  <gravity xyz="0 0 -9.8"/>
  <ode>
    <solver type="quick" dt="0.001" iters="10" sor="1.3"/>
    <constraints cfm="0.0" erp="0.1" contact_max_correcting_vel="10.0" contact_surface_layer="0.001"/>
  </ode>
</physics>
```

This is so frustrating...

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43327/controller-makes-robot-unstable-in-gazebo/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2012-09-07

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2012-09-07**:
Is the dynamics element that of a joint? If so, try lowering substantially the damping value. The same goes for the d gain in the controller.

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2012-09-09**:
Thanks Adolfo Rodriguez T that does help calm things down...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First isolate source of instability by setting

```
pid:
  p: 0
  i: 0
  d: 0
  i_clamp: 0
```

and

```
<dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
```

and

```
<physics type="ode">
  <gravity xyz="0 0 -9.8"/>
  <ode>
    <solver type="quick" dt="0.0001" iters="1000" sor="1.3"/>
    <constraints cfm="0.0" erp="0.1" contact_max_correcting_vel="10.0" contact_surface_layer="0.001"/>
  </ode>
</physics>
```

Then, change back the parameters one by one, and see which one(s) are the culprit of your instability.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LasseBoerresen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33452/lasseboerresen/) on 2018-12-28**:
Thnak you, I was having this problem with my robot collapsing after unpausing gazebo. It turns out, I had changed damping from 0.0 to 0.7, which caused the physics engine to fail. Setting it to 0.01 made it work again.